# Read variable from session in java on mule ESB

Tags: java, mule, session-variables

im developping a bookstore in Mule ESB and i need how can i read a session variable in java. My case is i query on my MYSQL the price of the book. I save this result in a session variable. To print the bill, i show the list of books with quantity and the price. I need recover the value of price.

Any solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access any variables, you need to first have access to the message. This can be done by either using a transformer which extends AbstractMessageTransformer or using a component which implements Callable. Once  you have that in place, you can use something similar to the one below:

```
public class TestComponent implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

         MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
         String sessionProperty = message.getProperty("mySessionProperty", PropertyScope.SESSION);
         ....
    }
}
```

Note that session properties may affect the memory, therefore you should only use them when necessary.

Comment: Okok, i understand it, but when i save on my session property an Object type "book" with attributes like (isbn, price, quantity...), how can access to this attributes=

Comment: The session property will be of type Object (Book) instead of String. Then you can access the attributes like you normally do in Java. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need is to implement a component that implements the [callable](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/Callable.html) interface. From the event context you can do a get message and then [get session property](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#getSessionProperty(java.lang.String)).